# How can I set image sizes and still have responsive images using the srcset attribute?

Tags: theme-development, images, responsive

I have this function in my theme to create thumbnail sizes.

```
  set_post_thumbnail_size( 620, 848, true );
            if (function_exists('add_image_size')){
                    add_image_size( 'compare-shop-logo', 150 );
                    add_image_size( 'compare-single-product-2', 250, 188, true );
                    add_image_size( 'compare-slider-image', 848, 487, true );
                    add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box', 400, 300, true);
                    add_image_size( 'compare-blog-box', 400, 225, true );
                    add_image_size( 'compare-quote-box', 408, 437, true );
            }
```

How come that if I change  the offer-box sizes, I lose the srcset and sizes in img tag? and is there a way to resize maintaining proportions?

```
<img width="400" height="300" src="myimage-400x300.jpg" class="embed-responsive-item wp-post-image" alt="image" srcset="myimage-1-400x300.jpg 400w, http:///myimage-250x188.jpg 250w" sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, 400px">
```

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The srcset attribute is constructed from images that are the same aspect ratio. Create a few of those and you'll be ok.

```
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box', 400, 300, true);
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box-2', 800, 600, true);
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box-3', 1200, 900, true);
```

for example. The fourth, boolean, argument tells WP to crop to the exact proportions.

To resize without cropping, use:

```
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box', 400, 9999, false);
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box-2', 800, 9999, false);
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box-3', 1200, 9999, false);
```

This assumes you want a particular width image and then whatever height the proportions require. You'll see some code around the web that uses values of `0` or `null` for the non-constrained dimension, but comments in the WP source code warn that this can have "unpredictable results."

If you'd rather scale proportionately while constraining the height then just use a huge value for the width:

```
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box', 9999, 400, false);
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box-2', 9999, 800, false);
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box-3', 9999, 1200, false);
```

If you want to maintain proportions but scale the image to fit within a certain space, say 400px by 400px, you can specify both maximum width and height but with cropping set to false:

```
add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box', 400, 400, false);
```

Note that if you are constraining by height then you may want to adjust the sizes attribute too, as that defaults to the width of the viewport with a maximum value of the specified image size's width.

Don't forget that you'll then need to regenerate image sizes for your existing images. There are plugins that do this well: Search for Regenerate Thumbnails in the plugin repository.

Comment: Do I have to reupload all my wp images or is there a way to reprocess all of them? thanks

Comment: There are plugins to reprocess them. Search for Regenerate Thumbnails in the plugin repository.

Comment: thanks, Can I resize without cropping, based on height instead of width? like add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box-2', 9999, 400, false);

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you do. Or you could set both parameters to 400 if the images must never be more than 400 wide or tall.

Comment: One more question: let's say I have an image 480x600 and I have to scale it maintaining proportions to a certain space: 400x400, I will use add_image_size( 'compare-offer-box', 400, 400, false);  but since the image has a different aspect ratio, what is going to happen to the added space (left and right)? how do I set the background color of the "empty" space added in order to maintain propoportion? thanks

Comment: That's more of a CSS question really. For really modern browsers look into the object-fit and object-position properties. Alternatively if there's a 400x400 element surrounding the images, use any of the CSS venturing techniques that are around.

Comment: About the thumbnails regeneration I strongly suggest to use wp-cli which can handle this task without installing extra plugins.

Comment: @FiNeX four years on, yes definitely. It’s what I do now. I found my host had a different php version on the command line, so knowing your way around the shell really helps.

Comment: Hi @AndyMacaulay-Brook, I didn't realize the comment date.