# Custom image size with srcset

Tags: images

I am having problem with custom sized srcset. [On this page](http://dk5.12a.myftpupload.com/) for the DANCE/ARTS/EVENTS section, I selected the Wordpress default "Medium Large" size for the thumbnail images. If I check the codes, I can see the images comes with the "srcset" attribute. Please check the [screenshot here](https://tinyurl.com/y4v7hyk8).

Then I have created a custom image size with the following code:

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); add_image_size( 'medium-cropped', 768, 514, true );`

I have regenerated all the images with the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin.

Now I have a custom size "Medium Cropped" to select in Elementor page builder. Please check the 4 thumbnails [on this page](http://dk5.12a.myftpupload.com/arts/gallery/). If you look at the codes, you will not see the srcset for them. Please check the second [screenshot here](https://tinyurl.com/y6d53gmn).

Can anyone suggest me the exact code to add in the functions.php file? I have read many tutorials but unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/243284/64435

If you do not create multiple versions of same proportions no data-src-set will be loaded since you have only one possible target